# How to Upadate bootstrap grid according to user requirements

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

Hello friends
I will try to adjust bootstrap grid like this but not successful is there any option to do like in the image this.
Below is my code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 400px;">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi , i have provided you answer.. i couldn't explain properly so if you don't understand let me know.

Comment: Do you want to make layout like Pinterest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two md4 in single parent div of md4 and then use md12 md12 in that. I have provide you snippet you can check that. Run full page snippet beacuse you have just used md-4 so it will work in desktop screen like this. or use xs-4 if you want same structure in mobile screen too

```html
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<style type="text/css">
    div p{
        background: black;
    }
</style>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-4" style="">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>

            </div>
             <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 100px;">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
             
        </div>
       
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Error is showing when i clicked on "Run code snippet.

Comment: @HTMLGuruz https://prnt.sc/ib9ptn see no error here... and run it on full page because on small screen it is not applied as he used md4

Comment: Thank you so much Rupal I understand it and done as i want. Thanks aganin !

Comment: Thanks @AlivetoDie